# List of Organs by Vascular Density?

Tags: medical-imaging, technology, internal-organs, capillary-capillaries

Could anyone please give me a list of the major organs in the human body with their vascular densities? 3D models and pictures of such are available, but calculating how much which organ has is very difficult.

I need an estimate of this so that I can calculate something for a video game.